# Как написать условие:

Tags: python, if

как написать такое условие: если количество символов <"> в строке ex"amp"le четное, то напечатать yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
example_string = 'ex"amp"le'
if example_string.count('"') % 2 == 0:
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

Comment: Или в одну строку:

    print 'yes' if example_string.count('"') % 2 == 0 else 'no'